# Google Analytics 4 Event Not Sent Despite GTM Tag Firing (RegExp Condition)

Tags: regex, events, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to create a custom event in Google Analytics 4 based on an existing event's parameter (form_id). My objective is to group multiple forms into a single event.

When I set the filtering condition in GA4 to "contains" and specify a single numerical ID (e.g. 1562), the event is sent correctly. However, issues arise when I switch to a regular expression for the form_id (e.g., "matches regexp" and then 1562|2106). In this case, while the GTM tag does fire, the event is not sent to GA4. I do test same form with ID=1562 in both scenarios.

The console shows an error: "Event processing aborted during augmentation."

I've ruled out other factors and confirmed that the issue is with this RegExp condition. According to the documentation, using a regular expression in this manner should be valid.

Any insights on what could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[working configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9TRy.png)
[non-working configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M74Uw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Update: Issue Resolved**

I wanted to update this question to inform anyone facing a similar issue that I've managed to resolve it.

The crux of the problem was that the `form_id` parameter was a numerical value. Regular expressions in Google Analytics 4 don't work as expected when trying to match numerical values.

The solution was to convert the variable to a string before applying the regular expression. Specifically, I modified my JavaScript code where `formId` is being generated like so:

```js
"formId" : event.detail.contactFormId.toString(),
```

After making this adjustment, the regular expression worked as expected, and the event was correctly sent to GA4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your custom-event from GTM. What I mean is that you need to create a Tag and set the related parameters.
Then, create a User-Defined Variable for the form-id and define how the value is set to it (for example if you send the value by **JavaScript** or it is a **dataLayer** value).

In my case in the following photo you see JS_storeIdVariable as the user_defined variable which I have chosen to get its value from a custom-defined `JavaScript` (JS) function. Remember, in this case, I am sending in front-end the value to the variable named storeId so that this function can read that value, something like

```
<script>
   window.storeId = <?php echo  $my_store_id ;?>;
</script>
```

[image: JS_storeIdVariable]

Then, as the trigger for the `Tag` you have created you should create a `Trigger` which the **filter you want** is applicable here.
Do something like the photo below **BUT** you need to set the values based on what you need:

Also pay attention to the trigger type and select something which is meaningful to your case.

[image]

Comment: Hi Shila! Thank you very much for your  answer and suggestion! It was exactly my plan B, for the case if I won't succeed solve it on GA side. I did solve the issue by converting formId value to string! Apparently, google's regexp does not wotk with numerical values, just the strings (added update to my post). 
Have a wonderful day! 